# Zebra Bluetooth heat printer prints random characters instead an image, using ShinyBluetoothLE (2.7.3) in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, zebra-printers, bluetooth-printing

Im developing an application that prints an image of a voucher in a Zebra heath printer via bluetooth using SkiaSharp (2.88.5) and SkiaSharp.Views.Forms (2.88.5) to generate the voucher image and ShinyBluetoothLE (2.7.3) to **print that image via bluetooth** in Xamarin Forms, but when printing, instead of the voucher image I get a bunch of random characters. What am I doing wrong? Is something missing from my code?

MainViewModel.cs

```
using BluetoothTest.Interfaces;
using BluetoothTest.Model;
using SkiaSharp;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace BluetoothTest.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        byte[] globalImageByte = null;
         
        /*000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*/
        public ICommand PrintCommand { get; protected set; }

        public string selectedDevice;

        /*000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*/

        public List<string> pairedDevices;

        /*000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*/

        private Voucher_Model _voucher;

        public Voucher_Model Voucher
        {
            get { return _voucher; }
            set { _voucher = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private SKSurface _surface;

        public SKSurface Surface
        {
            get { return _surface; }
        }

        /*000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*/

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _voucher = new Voucher_Model()
            {
                Customer = "Edgar Allan Poe",
                Date = "20/08/2023",
                Detalles = new List<Detalle_Model>()
                {
                    new Detalle_Model()
                    {
                        Product = "Product 1",
                        Price = 100
                    },

                    new Detalle_Model()
                    {
                        Product = "Product 2", 
                        Price = 200
                    },
                }
            };

            // Initialize the command
            PrintCommand = new Command(Prntbutton_Clicked);

            GetDeviceList();
            //Crear comando que ejecute la seleccion de dispositivo
        }

        /*000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*/

        private List<string> GetDeviceList()
        {
            IPrintService service = DependencyService.Get<IPrintService>();
            var getDeviceList = service.GetDeviceList();

            if (getDeviceList == null)
                return null;

            if (getDeviceList.Count == 0)
            {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "No Bluetooth Device found", "Ok");
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                pairedDevices = new List<string>(getDeviceList);
                return pairedDevices;
            }
        }

        public async Task<byte[]> GenerateVoucher(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintGLSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
            SKPaint paint = new SKPaint();

            /*Config*/
            paint.Color = SKColors.Black;
            paint.TextSize = 30;

            // Draw the background 
            canvas.Clear(SKColors.WhiteSmoke);

            // Draw the client name
            canvas.DrawText($"Customer: {Voucher.Customer}", new SKPoint(10, 40), paint);

            // Draw the date
            canvas.DrawText($"Date: {Voucher.Date}", new SKPoint(10, 80), paint);

            // Draw the list of details
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var detalle in _voucher.Detalles)
            {
                // Draw the product name
                canvas.DrawText(detalle.Product, new SKPoint(10, 160 + 20 * index), paint);

                // Draw the price
                canvas.DrawText(detalle.Price.ToString("C"), new SKPoint(250, 160 + 20 * index), paint);

                index++;
            }

            // Convert the canvas to an SKData
            var image = surface.Snapshot();
            var skdata = image.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 100);
            //Convert skdata to byteArray;
            var data = skdata.ToArray();

            globalImageByte = data;
            // Return the byte array
            return data;
        }

        public async void Prntbutton_Clicked()
        {
            var sel_device = Preferences.Get("SelectedDevice", "");
            IPrintService service = DependencyService.Get<IPrintService>();
            await service.Print(sel_device, globalImageByte);

            globalImageByte = null;
        }


    }
}
```

BluetoothServiceRenderer.cs (in Android project)

```
using Android.Bluetooth;
using BluetoothTest.Droid.Services;
using BluetoothTest.Interfaces;
using Java.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(BluetoothServiceRenderer))]
namespace BluetoothTest.Droid.Services
{
    public class BluetoothServiceRenderer : IPrintService
    {
        public IList<string> GetDeviceList()
        {
            using (BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter)
            {
                var btdevice = bluetoothAdapter?.BondedDevices.Select(i => i.Name).ToList();
                return btdevice;
            }
        }

        public async Task Print(string deviceName, byte[] imgbyte)
        {
            BluetoothDevice myDevice;

            using (BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter)
            {
                myDevice = (from bd in bluetoothAdapter?.BondedDevices
                                            where bd?.Name == deviceName
                                            select bd).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            try
            {
                using (BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = myDevice?.
                    CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                    UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")))
                {
                    bluetoothSocket?.Connect();
                    byte[] buffer = imgbyte;
                    bluetoothSocket?.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                   
                    bluetoothSocket.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw exp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IPrintService.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BluetoothTest.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPrintService
    {
        IList<string> GetDeviceList();
        Task Print(string deviceName, byte[] imgByte);
    }
}
```

VoucherPreview_Page.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia ="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="BluetoothTest.View.VoucherPreview_Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Picker WidthRequest="250"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    x:Name="MyDevices" 
                    SelectedIndexChanged="MyDevicePicker_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    Title="Selecionar Impresora"
                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding .}"/>

            <ScrollView>
                <skia:SKGLView x:Name="voucherImage"
                               HeightRequest="700"
                               WidthRequest="400"
                               PaintSurface="canvasView_PaintSurface"/>
            </ScrollView>
            
            <Button Text="Print"
                    TextColor="White" 
                    FontFamily="PoppinsSemiBold"
                    FontSize="17"
                    WidthRequest="170"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    CornerRadius="5"
                    x:Name="Prntbutton"
                    Command="{Binding PrintCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

VoucherPreview_Page.xaml.cs

```
using BluetoothTest.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace BluetoothTest.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class VoucherPreview_Page : ContentPage
    {
        public string selectedDevice;
        MainViewModel _viewModel = new MainViewModel();
        public VoucherPreview_Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = _viewModel;

            MyDevices.ItemsSource = _viewModel.pairedDevices;
        }

        void MyDevicePicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            selectedDevice = ((Picker)sender).SelectedItem as string;
            Preferences.Set("SelectedDevice", selectedDevice);
        }

        private void canvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Forms.SKPaintGLSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            var imgbyte = _viewModel.GenerateVoucher(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to print the image that appears in the voucher preview

Comment: you appear to just be writing `imgbyte` to the printer socket without sending any sort of print command?  You generally need to tell the printer that you're printing an image before sending the data

Comment: thanks for answer, do you have any example of that? beacuse It works when you try to print an string instead byte[]